# Logging and viewing custom events in Azure Blob / Table

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

I'd like to log some business events from my WebApp (e.g. an invoice was issued or user updated some record and i'd like to see what was changed) and use some already existing tools to view them. My first approach was to use Azure Table Storage along with [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)

My example event object looks like this:

```
public abstract class ApplicationEvent : TableEntity
{
    public string ClientIP { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; } // JSON document with audit

    public ApplicationEvent()
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        PartitionKey = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM}", now);
        RowKey = string.Format("{0:dd HH:mm:ss.fff}-{1}", now, Guid.NewGuid());
    }
}
```

At small events volume it seems reasonable solution. But then again - as the log will grow viewing/searching logs can become very inefficient. I've thought of creating one table per month/week but it doesn't feel right.

I've read about using blobs to store the log but i can't find any existing tool that user can use to browse/filter these events in my custom format (i want to be able to see all my ApplicationEvent properties). So the question is:
- which is better: table or blob? Or maybe something else?
- if blob is the way to go - how to efficiently create/write custom events to Blob Storage and how to view those events in human readable form?

Comment: Looks like your existing PartitionKey & RowKey design is good enough - you can query the logs in a given time range via PartitionKey & RowKey filter. What's your concern here? Why do you need multiple tables?

Comment: First and foremost: according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-design-guide this an anti-pattern. They encourage logging to blob. Secondly, with big number of logs it will be hard to browse them "tail-wise" with Storage Explorer.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed an anti-pattern if your logging throughput is high, since it will result in a hot partition. Why not adopt the solution suggested in that design guide? You can enable analytics in your storage account and check how those blobs are organized, and implement your logging mechanism just like that.